# Convert Dataset or Datagridview into text with column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox, dataset

I try to create my own SQL QUERY Analyzer.
It works perfectly with a datagridview.

But I try to add a version that offers the text mode version. And I want this text mode having data in columns, to have a clean view.

This code that I try is working to put data in a textbox in columns, but it's VERY SLOW!!!
(Other thing, the data seems not to be align in column, but If I copy to contains of the textbox in Notepad, it looks great).

```
For increm = 0 To DataGridSQLQuery.RowCount - 2
    For inc = 0 To DataGridSQLQuery.ColumnCount - 1
        str = ""
        str = str.PadRight(DataGridSQLQuery.Columns(inc).Width - DataGridSQLQuery.Rows(increm).Cells(inc).Value.ToString.Length, padvide)
        txtMessageErreur.Text = txtMessageErreur.Text + DataGridSQLQuery.Rows(increm).Cells(inc).Value.ToString + str + " "
    Next
     txtMessageErreur.Text = txtMessageErreur.Text & Environment.NewLine
 Next
```

Is there's a way to link data to create the text mode version in a second. Can I use another tool than a textbox Maybe ?

thanks for your help

Comment: if there are a lot of rows and/or columns use stringbuilder instead of a string variable.  Strings are immutable, so `str` has to be recreated over and over

Comment: @Plutonix Great I get my text box filled in less than a second. I use this line : TextBoxSTR.Append(DataGridSQLQuery.Rows(increm).Cells(inc).Value.ToString + str + " ")

Comment: **Now the only problem left is that the text view in the textbox doesn't have a column look. The data are not aligned. And curiously If I paste the result in notepad, it gives me the result that I want. Do I need something else than a textbox to display my result ?**

Comment: a listview will do columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so `str` has to be recreated over and over.  If there are a lot of rows or columns, use a stringbuilder:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder

For r As Integer = 0 To DataGridSQLQuery.RowCount - 2
    For c = 0 To DataGridSQLQuery.ColumnCount - 1
        sb.Append( your text to add to the string )

        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)
        txtMessageErreur.Text = sb.Tostring

        sb.Clear      ' reset for next iteration
    Next c
Next r
```

The text will not line up in a textbox or listbox like columns, unless you use a monospace font.  `W` takes more room than `i`.  PadLeft/Right will help but not a lot

Comment: Great, Using this font : Courier New, gives me what I need. I didn't know about monospace font before. Thanks for the help !